# Beam equation is neccesary condition for minimum of specific functional.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

The beam equation is given by:

$Mu^{(4)}(x)+Nu''(x) = f(x) \; x \in [0,L]$

This is supposed to represent the bending of a beam of length $L$ when a sectional mass density $f(x) \ge 0$ acts on the beam.

I have to show that a candidate to be a minimum of the functional:

$\mathcal{F}[u] = \int_{0}^L \Big(M \frac{u''(x)^2}{2} - N \frac{u'(x)}{2}-f(x)u(x)\Big) dx$

defined on a suitable set, has to verify the beam equation.

I'm looking for hints on where to define this functional and whether I can use any intermediate results. Otherwise, I'll have to reproduce the proof from other variational problems. What surprises me here is that there aren't any boundary conditions.

**My approach**

We have the functional $\mathcal{F}[u] = \int_{0}^L \Big( M \frac{u''(x)^2}{2} - N \frac{u'(x)^2}{2} - f(x)u(x)\Big) dx$ and we can denote $F(x,u(x),u'(x),u''(x)) = M \frac{u''(x)^2}{2} - N \frac{u'(x)^2}{2} - f(x)u(x)$.

Now we do variations $g(s) = \mathcal{F}[\overline{u}+s\phi]$ where $\overline{u}$ is the (possible) minimum of the functional. Therefore we have that $g'(0) = 0$. Doing the calculations yields: $$0 = \int_{x_0}^{x_1} \frac{dF}{dy} (x,\overline{u}(x),\overline{u}'(x),\overline{u}''(x)) \phi(x) + \frac{dF}{dz} F(x,\overline{u}(x),\overline{u}'(x),\overline{u}''(x)) \phi'(x) + \frac{dF}{dp} F(x,\overline{u}(x),\overline{u}'(x),\overline{u}''(x)) \phi''(x)$$

Comment: It's only got to satisfy the beam equation on the the open interval (0,L)

Comment: @NotMike actually it seems that you're right, perhaps i could put the domain of $\mathcal{F}$ so that equation is verfied in $0,L$

Comment: Or you could simply observe that since the set $\{0, L\}$ has measure zero, the value of $F$ is unaffected by the values of $u$ on the end-points; provided $u$ is sufficiently smooth on $(0,L)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Giving

$$
F(x,u,u',u'') = \frac 12 M u''-\frac 12 N u'-f(x)u
$$

we have according to Euler-Lagrange conditions

$$
F_u-\left(F_{u'}\right)'+\left(F_{u''}\right)'' = M u^{(4)}-f(x)=0
$$

which obeys the beam line equation.